# I moved a function outside the class and made const. Now the function does not work

Tags: reactjs, class, constants, setstate

I moved the function **addONe** outside the class **Counter**. After doing this the function addOne does not work anymore, but on the other side I dont receive any error. My question is what I did wrong that the **const addOne** doesnt work?

```
import React from 'react';

const addOne = () => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
                count: prevState.count + 1
            }
        })
    }


export default class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.minusOne = this.minusOne.bind(this);
        this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            count: 0
        }
    }


    // addOne() {
    //     this.setState((prevState) => {
    //         return {
    //             count: prevState.count + 1
    //         }
    //     })
    // }

    minusOne() {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
                count: prevState.count - 1
            }
        })
    }

    reset() {
        this.setState(() => {
            return {
               count: 0// count: 0
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Count: {this.state.count}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.addOne}>+1</button>
                <button onClick={this.minusOne}>-1</button>
                <button onClick={this.reset}>reset</button>
            </div>
        )
    } 
}
```

Comment: `this.addOne` would be undefined in your class wouldn't it, since you moved it outside of the class's scope. Therefor the `onClick` handler attached to your button will not do anything.

Comment: I got it. In this case, what should I do to make it work, still keeping the function outside the class?

Comment: For starters you also shouldn't use an arrow function. Instead you should use a regular function and then bind `this` to it in the constructor like you did with `minusOne`. It'll probably work after you do that and also change `this.addOne` to simply `addOne`

Comment: the ````addOne```` was inside the ````Counter```` class at the beginning and it worked  fine. Just tried to take it outside the class and try it work.

Comment: You can leave the `addOne` outside of the class (it's not a good idea but you can do it), but you still have to bind `this` or else `this.setState` will be undefined. Try it without and observe what errors you get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It cannot work.

You are accessing `this.setState` inside your function, but you don't have any `setState` method in your scope, because it is proper of the `React.Component` class.

The real question is: why you want to move out the class the `addOne` function?

#### Edit due to your comment

If you are learning, you need a more technical explanation :)

First, you need to access the `setState` method of `React.Component` class outside of it, in your addOne function. We need to bind to this function a context where the `this.setState` exists. What better than the context of the component itself?

Let's update the render method replacing this line:

```
<button onClick={this.addOne}>+1</button>
```

with this one:

```
<button onClick={addOne.bind(this)}>+1</button>
```

What's happening here? The function `addOne` is receiving an external context (in this case, `this`). This context will be used as the `this` keyword inside the function. Technically, binding another context creates a new bounded function, but this is another matter that we don't care here.

If you try this little edit it still won't work.

That's because you are declaring `addOne` as a lambda function expression. In ES6, lambda functions can't have other contexts bound to them.

In fact, if you transform your addOne from a lambda function expression to a function declaration, like this:

```
function addOne() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    count: prevState.count + 1
  }));
}
```

...you'll see that the increase works properly :)

Hope it helps you understant what's going on here.

**Keeping ES6 syntax**

Now, using ES6 lambda function expressions is not impossibile, it just move the same problem a little sideway. We cannot bind another context, but we can keep a closure on it calling a method that resides or has the right context.

For instance we can transform the `addOne` function expression into a higher order function, that takes the `setState` and return the click handler you need:

```
const addOne = setState => () =>
  setState(prevState => ({
    count: prevState.count + 1
  }))
```

Now, in the render method, we may think to use it like:

```
<button onClick={addOne(this.setState)}>+1</button>
```

passing the `setState` as a function reference.

The subtle problem now is that the `setState` inside the `addOne` function doesn't have it's original context bound!

We can solve it with:

```
<button onClick={addOne(this.setState.bind(this))}>+1</button>
```

#### Edit due to your last comment

These syntaxes behaves exactly the same:

```
const addOne = setState => () =>
  setState(prevState => ({
    count: prevState.count + 1
  }))

const addOne = setState => () =>
  setState(prevState => {
    return { count: prevState.count + 1 }
  })
```

The way they work the same, is because with lambda function expressions, if you have a single statement as the body of your function, the result of the evaluation of that statement is automatically returned.

This means that a lambda function can be as short as:

```
const five = () => 5
// five() returns immediate value 5
```

Said that, when you have:

```
prevState => {
  return { count: prevState.count + 1 }
}
```

you are creating a body with a single statement that returns a plain object.

Do you see the similarity? You are doing the same thing: having a single statement that returns something.

The first thing that may come up to your mind might be to rewrite it omitting the `return` keyword like:

```
prevState => {
  count: prevState.count + 1
}
```

But this won't work. It will give you a syntax error due to the colon character that shouldn't be there. It shouldn't be there because if a lambda function expression body is defined as a block (wrapping everything with `{}`), it is supposed to have more than one statement and, maybe, a `return` keyword.

To make it work, we need to treat the plain object definition as a single statement, and we do that by wrapping it into rounded parenthesis, like:

```
prevState => ({
  count: prevState.count + 1
})
```

Again, hope it helps :)

Comment: I want to move the function outside the class to learn how to do it properly. I want to split another project for separate files instead of keepping everything in one.

Comment: explain me please one more thing if this syntax works the same way: 1. export const addOne = setState => () =>
setState(prevState => ({
        count: prevState.count + 1
})); and 2. export const addOne = setState => () => 
setState((prevState) => {
    return {
        count: prevState.count +1
    }
})